Let $L = \mathbb Q(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}})$ What is its degree over $\mathbb Q$
Let $L = \mathbb Q(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}})$ What is its degree over $\mathbb Q$.
So what I did is this, let $a = \sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}$. consider $x = \sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}$ then
$x^2 = 2 + \sqrt{3}$ then $x^2 -2 \sqrt{3}$ then $x^4 - 4x^2 + 4 = 3$ and so that
$p(x) = x^4 -4x^2 + 1 = 0$. So by construction this polynomial satisfies the equation $p(a) = 0 $.I believe that this polynomial is irreducible but I'm having difficulties proving it, and I haven't been able to use Eisenstein or Gauss lemma.
Now the roots of this polynomials are
$$\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}, -\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}, \sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}, -\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}} $$
So $p$ can't be written as linear factors over the rationals, so it has to be written as a product of two quadratic polynomials, so I believe that there is no quadratic polynomial having any of the numbers above as roots, but I haven't been able to prove it. I tried using the quadratic formula but I couldn't find any contradiction, I also tried expanding the coefficients and obtained a system of 5 equations but I couldnt get a contradiction either. How could I prove that $p$ is irreducible over the rationals? or is there another method to find the degree of the extension $L$?

As $[L:\mathbb Q]=[L:\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3)]\cdot[\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3): \mathbb Q]=2[L:\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3)]$, so $2\mid[L:\mathbb Q]$.
And $[L:\mathbb Q]\le 4$, $[L:\mathbb Q]$ is either $2$ or $4$.
If $[L:\mathbb Q]=2$, then $L=\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3)$.
Therefore $a+b\sqrt 3 = \sqrt{2+\sqrt 3}$, for $a,b\in \mathbb Q$. That is, $a^2+3b^2=2$ and $2ab=1$.
Note that $\sqrt{2+\sqrt 3}$ is an algebraic integer, hence $a,b\in\mathbb Z$, $2ab=1$ cannot be satisfied.

Another way to finish: let $\alpha=\sqrt{2+\sqrt 3}$, then $\sqrt{2-\sqrt 3} = \frac{1}{\alpha}\in L$, $(\alpha+\frac{1}{\alpha})^2 = 6$, so $\sqrt{6}\in L$. This implies $\sqrt{2}\in L$. So $L$ has at least two distinct subextensions of degree $2$: $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3)$ and $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$. (Therefore we can even conclude the Galois group must be isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, because $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ has only one subgroup of order $2$.)

Notice that the polynomial $p(x)$ has got no rational root. Hence if it is reducible, it must split as product of two quadratic polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$.  Suppose
$$x^4-4x^2+1 = (x^2+bx+c)(x^2+dx+e)$$.
Then, observe that
$$ce=1 \tag{1},$$
$$c+e+bd=-4\tag{2},$$
$$be+cd =0\tag{3},$$
and
$$b+d=0\tag{4}.$$
Now, from $(4)$, we may conclude that
$$be+ed=0 \tag{5}.$$
From $(3)$ and $(5)$ it now follows that either $d=0$ or $c=e$. If $d=0$, then $b=0$ and hence $c+e=-4$ from $(2)$. Solving for $c$ and $e$ with $ce=1$ and $c+e=-4$, we get irrational values for $c$ and $e$. Hence $d\neq 0$. Thus $c=e$. This implies, from $(1)$ that $c=e =1$ or $c=e=-1$.
If $c=e=1$, then, from $(2)$, $bd=-6$. We have $b+d=0$. Solving for $b$ and $d$ from this, we get irrational values for $b$ and $d$.
If $c=e=-1$, then, $bd =-2$. Now also, we get irrational values for $b$ and $d$.
Hence, there can exist no rationals $b,c, d,$ and $e$ such that
$$x^4-4x^2+1 = (x^2+bx+c)(x^2+dx+e).$$
